Which mate should I choose for the next two parts?
There are two such parts in Solidworks.

I need to put the ball into the dent and have it rotate there in all directions. But SW says that he does not have suitable mates for this.
How to solve a problem?
Edit: I managed to do this through a tangency, but the ball “passes through” the second body. How to fix it?

Mate the origins together with coincident. If they don't line up with the centre of rotation, add reference sketches and mate the sketch points.

Point to point mate + an angle limit would be all the restrictions you need

@Abel I did this using additional mates, but it would be more convenient to somehow indicate something like “this object should not touch or go beyond the limits of this one.”

@JonathanRSwift What do you think about working with restrictions?

I... Don't know what you mean by "restrictions"...

@JonathanRSwift I already figured it out, they meant bounds on the movement of objects.
